# Cross database query using dblink

Tags: postgresql, dblink

I'd like to use dblink in postgres to copy data from a local database to a remote one. This what I came up with:

`SELECT * FROM dblink('archive', 'INSERT INTO data SELECT * FROM local.data')`

It wont work and I think I understand why. I get the error `relation "local.data" does not exist`, If possible, Id like to run this inside a stored procedure on the local database, in other words I want to push the data to the 'archive' server, rather than pull it to the 'archive'.

How can I tell postgres to look in the local database? How can I address the local database from inside the dblink query?

Comment: I'm no sure what you want, so do you look on local data base and insert new register on remote database? Remember that you need type the resultset at the end.

Comment: @rray That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this through dblink, but was able to do it using postgres_fwd. I had to create a foreign table first associated with the table I want to insert into.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER archive FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'localhost',  dbname 'archive_db');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER SERVER archive OPTIONS (user 'user', password 'pass');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE archivedata (..) SERVER archive OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'data');

INSERT INTO archivedata SELECT * FROM data;
```

Comment: Yes, a foreign table is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To copy rows from local database to remote database you should run the `insert` statement on remote host and make the search on local host. the syntax is this:

```
INSERT INTO t1(id, name, description, "date")
    SELECT id_foo, full_name, des, "date" FROM 
    dblink('host= ? user= ? password= ? dbname= externaldb'::text,
    'SELECT id, name, description, "date" FROM t2'::text, false)
    ttemp(id integer, name character varying,  description character varying, "date" date)
)
```

Change the `?` for the local information.

Comment: I'm converting an existing stored procedure and moving it to the remote server would cause some extra changes. I'm trying to avoid this if possible.

Comment: @SlackGroverglow: what do you mean with "avoid this"? you want to insert into a local table - that's the way to do it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this solution is not the best for me because I will have multiple servers pushing data to the archive. I dont think the archive server will be fast enough to pull from all the servers by itself.